# Creating SSH Terminal Wrapper

Tags: ssh, gnome-terminal, scripting

I'm new to scripting, but somewhat familiar with Linux.  I am actually using this on a Fedora16 build, with Gnome3 and gnome-terminal... fyi.

I flip through all sorts of ssh terminals all day long and I thought it would be nice to create a ssh script called lambda that contains information that is sent to a terminal_wrapper script that accepts all sorts of variables and creates a new gnome-terminal based on those given variables.  The information I would like would be to rename the title, change bg and fg colors, and start an ssh in a new gnome-terminal window.

I feel like I'm close to getting the ssh to work, but I'm missing something.  Here is what I've got for my ssh script for lambda:

`terminal_wrapper user lambda.company.com`

And here is my terminal_wrapper:

`gnome-terminal --title=$2 -e ssh $1 $2`

It opens a new window for me, renames it to the lambda.company.com, and then sits there and closes after a second.

Any help?  Thanks.

Comment: I think it should be `gnome-terminal --title=$2 -e ssh "$1"@"$2"`

Comment: You may also want to look at getopt (and either error checking or setting defaults) http://aplawrence.com/Unix/getopts.html

Comment: Changing it to "$1"@"$2" seems to make sense, but doesn't seem to work for me.  Anything else I might be missing?  I'll check out getopts too.

Comment: Try without the quotes `$1@$2`

Comment: Nope.  Didn't work either.

Comment: How about changing your prompt on each server to set the colours on your terminal? http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html ; this will work across any machine you start a terminal from and not just your main desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, use this command:

```
gnome-terminal --title=$2 --command "ssh $1@$2" --window &
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying a couple more things a friend suggested that maybe the -e command on gnome-terminal expects a complete command.  After changing the code to the following it works:

`gnome-terminal --title=$2 -e "ssh $1@$2"`

Thanks for your input.